# Expand integer macro inside quoted string

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, c-strings, exim

While contributing to exim, I saw many values where hard-coded :

```
uschar filebuffer[256];
(void)sprintf(CS filebuffer, "%.256s.db", filename);
 rc = lf_check_file(-1, filebuffer, S_IFREG, modemask, owners, owngroups,
  "dbm", errmsg);
if (rc < 0)        /* stat() failed */
  {
  (void)sprintf(CS filebuffer, "%.256s.dir", filename);
  rc = lf_check_file(-1, filebuffer, S_IFREG, modemask, owners, owngroups,
    "dbm", errmsg);
   if (rc == 0)     /* x.dir was OK */
     {
     (void)sprintf(CS filebuffer, "%.256s.pag", filename);
     rc = lf_check_file(-1, filebuffer, S_IFREG, modemask, owners, owngroups,
       "dbm", errmsg);
     }
   }
 }
```

As the code isn’t windows specific, every`256`values should be converted to`PATH_MAX`.

I know that expanding macros inside quoted strings isn’t possible, but that string concatenation is trivial :

```
#define STR "string"
size_t len=strlen("part"STR"part 2");
```

However, things like :

```
"%."PATH_MAX".db"
```

Shouldn’t work because`PATH_MAX`expands to an integer, not a string.
So is there a way to do this without calling a function that convert integers to C strings ?

Comment: Why are you casting function calls instead of analyzing their return values?

Comment: @iharob : because I didn’t wrote this piece of code. Just read the first line, it’s part of exim code I didn’t modified. Many things are done wrong : most of the code isn’t indented at all and there are even returns values of calls to`malloc()`which aren’t checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do this is to use a `*` in your format string, which will cause it to take the value from your argument list.  For example:

```
printf("%.*s\n", 3, "abcde");
```

This is  equivalent to:

```
printf("%.3s\n", "abcde");
```

That way you can use `PATH_MAX` or any other value to control the format without having to worry about how they're defined (e.g., whether they contain parentheses or addition operators, etc.)

Comment: Sorry, had to dummy-edit to remove the DV. You really have a point

Answer (score 1):

You can stringify a macro argument by using the `#` operator. But you need an indirect macro invocation to expand the argument:

```
#define Q(x) Q_(x)
#define Q_(x) #x
```

So you could do something like:

```
char filebuffer[PATH_MAX + 10];
sprintf(filebuffer, "%." Q(PATH_MAX)"s.db", filename);
```

The existing code limits the string sibstitution to 256 characters but then adds a file extension (and a NUL terminator) which will be a buffer overflow when the length is close to 256. I used an arbitrary 10-byte overallocation above, but it would be better to use a checked-length sprintf like `snprintf`. That would have the additional advantage of not requiring macro games.

Comment: @user2284570 no, it would not. `#` stringifies the value attached to it. Doing it the way you show would produce `"%.PATH_MAX.db"` instead of `"%.256.db"`. You need to pass `PATH_MAX` to a macro to evaluate it to its value, and then stringify that value.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Actually, what OP wrote in that comment would stringify only the `(` (assuming that it appeared in a macro replacement, because at least in theory, # is an error outside of macro replacements.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it uses compile-time processing like the original. If you just would elaborate a bit more.

Comment: @Olaf You're joking, right?  What if `PATH_MAX` is defined as `(2*512)`?  Then this solution cannot possibly work, ever.  It's the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @tom: i agree that there are better solutions than relying on macros to be simple numbers. However, I don't believe length interpolation is really any better, since it depends on a manual computation of how many extra characters are required by the format string; in general, snprintf is the solution even if you have to find an implementation for systems so old that they lack it, of which there can't be that many any more.

Comment: @TomKarzes: Good point, I really forgot about that. As an embedded engineer, I tend to accept such restrictions, because run-time (and often code/constant space) is precious. For the code shown, It still might be a suitable solution (better than magic values anyway).

Comment: Anyway, it's always good to know how to stringify, and that was what the OP actually asked for.